# Traversing and storing in an Array List or List

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I having trouble with the logic of a project. I need to save user input (an address) in textboxes to an Arraylist or List. Then when the user hits the back button, access the arraylist or list and display the the stored values. I having trouble with the logic, I have the arraylist created and when a user hits the add button, the values are adding to the arraylist. The problem is I don't understand how to post the stored values together, i.e. City, State, Zip,ID, is all stored in the array, how does the back button assign all of the right values? I would like it to where the ComboBox on the right side of the application allows the user to select a state. When a state is selected, all of the package ID numbers of packages destined for that state are displayed in the ListBox. I'm looking for advise or tips on how to make this work. Thank you for any help.

*EDITED*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    //these lines of code imports the date/time function and the random function 
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    String addresses;
    String cities;
    String states;
    String zipcodes;
    string num = "";

    public List<Order> orderlist = new List<Order>();

    public class Order
    {
        public string city { set; get; }
        public string zipcode { set; get; }
        public string state { set; get; }
        public string orderNum { set; get; }
        public string address { set; get; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void scanBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this displays the current date and time in the arrived at textbox
        arrivedAtTextbox.Text = "" + time;

        //this code generates a random number and converts to a string to be displayed
        int id = rnd.Next(1000);
        num = id.ToString();
        packageIDTextbox.Text = num;

        //these lines of code enables the fields after the scan button was clicked
        addressTextbox.IsEnabled = true;
        cityTextbox.IsEnabled = true;
        zipCodeTextbox.IsEnabled = true;
        stateComboBox.IsEnabled = true;

        //this code sets the focus to the address field
        addressTextbox.Focus();

        addresses = addressTextbox.Text;
        cities = cityTextbox.Text;          
        zipcodes = zipCodeTextbox.Text;
        states = stateComboBox.Text;


    }

    //Add Button
    private void addBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Order data = new Order();
        data.address = addresses;
        data.city = cities;
        data.zipcode = zipcodes;
        data.state = states;
        data.orderNum = num;

        orderlist.Add(data);

    }
    //Remove Button
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var order in orderlist)
        {

        }
    }

    //Next Button
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var order in orderlist)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should mention what kind of app this is (it seems to be a web app of some type).  Consider creating a class (or set of classes) with properties like address, city, etc. rather than individual fields.  Then you can track things as a single unit (for example, in a database, or in a list of data entries, etc.)

Comment: @Flydog57 Your right, I didn't think of that. I think using classes would be the way it should go, I'll do that now. Thank you

Comment: First thing first you need to not use `ArrayList`

Comment: @TheGeneral use List instead?

Comment: Yeah `List<T>` would be a good place to start, `arrayList` is a very outdated early .net construct

Comment: Ok, I made changes. I'm now using a List instead of an ArrayList. Also I'm now now using a class to define what an order is. Now I'm still stuck on how to print these stored items to textboxs that they came from.